# php dropdown session is removed when I delete internet cookies/history

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, cookies

I have a dropdown that keeps the selected value.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['gender'])){
    $_SESSION['gender'] = $_POST['gender'];
}

?>

<select name="gender" id="edit-select">
    <option value="0">Your gender</option>
    <option value="Male" <?php echo isset($_SESSION['gender']) && $_SESSION['gender'] == "Male" ? "selected" : "" ?> >Male</option>
    <option value="Female" <?php echo isset($_SESSION['gender']) && $_SESSION['gender'] == "Female" ? "selected" : "" ?>>Female</option>
</select>
```

The only issue with this is that anytime I delete my internet history/cookies, it'll delete that dropdown session; so it'll revert to it's default option. Is there a way for it's session to not be deleted?

Comment: Don't delete your cookies. That's where the session identifier is stored.

Comment: Yes I see that. Is there a way around it?  How do other websites that have dropdown user options do it?

Comment: Use a database and a login system to store the preferences of authenticated users.

Answer (score 0):

when you Delete your history/cookies that mean already you delete all sessions or cookies so you can't restore it again but you can use DB Mysql to store this information and you can control it by using Jquery  if this form is temporary  you can also use DB for example

when the user submit or move from x to z delete session where =id

Comment: I have a database where the user's information is stored.  I can retrieve the gender information from db and show it on a page. That all works.  I am just having hard time getting that same info show up in the select fields of edit profile page.  Using the above html code, can you add in the query that retrieves the info from db?  It'll help me see where it's exactly placed.

Comment: You can retrieve gender information by using ajax request using Jquery it's too easy to create it just look at 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

you know , create ajax request for gender only so when the user moving around your website each page will do ajax request and the response  will be gender M/F and put it in Gender Div .